# Getting history mode to work with Vue app deployed on Google Cloud

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform

I managed to break my site on Google cloud. If you navigate to my domain, it works fine http://www.quantumjs.com/

but if you go to a route my app directly, GC isn't redirecting to index.

ie http://www.quantumjs.com/events

I followed this tutorial but modified it for my vue app

https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-deploy-a-static-react-site-to-google-cloud-platform-55ff0bd0f509

I thought this app.yaml would do the job:

`runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist`

EDIT

this was my working solution

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(js|css|png|jpg))$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*\.(js|css|png|jpg)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try redirecting all your url access to the `index.html`

```
handlers:
  # handle static files, change the path according to your need
- url: /(.*\.(js|css))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(js|css)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

Read more in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers).

Comment: thanks but this is also redirecting js files to index, see if you can check the network tab for js files, ie http://www.quantumjs.com/js/app.597347fa.js

Comment: @Nikos Add a handler to handle the static files/folders, and use the `/.*` for catch all. edited answer to give you a simple idea how it works.

Comment: I modified your answer a bit