# How to allow users to type address when using vue spa on google cloud storage

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-storage, vue-router, gcloud

We are hosting a vue spa on google storage buckets and it works find for the main index page and for the links on the page but you are unable to type a url in and go the the page because google cloud tries to find the file instead of using vue router

If i switch off history mode it works because its a # instead of a path but we need history mode on for this to work

```
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Here is the XML data for not found pages

I want to have users able to type in the url and goes to that page. I would like to keep it on GCloud Storage buckets if possible if not a vm is fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563340/getting-history-mode-to-work-with-vue-app-deployed-on-google-cloud

Comment: @MattOestreich is there a way to do it with Gcloud Storage because that uses app engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by setting the 404 page to index.html

Comment: Hello @ThatPurpleGuy. I use this technic also, but I still see an issue with „deep linking“. Let us say I have „https://spa.com/user/settings?setup=success“. When my server redirects to this URL, after some third party callback (http status 303), Google will return index.html, but Vue does not render the settings page. If I type this URL in the browser, the correct UI is rendered. Any idea?

Comment: @abedurftig This is probably best if you ask it as it's own question, if you hop in the vuejs discord they can probably help faster aswell. There is probably  a router setting that you need to setup but I would need more info.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but doesn't matter, you can just take care of 404's in the router, was trying for a long time to figure this out and this is the only solution I know of, thank you dearly!

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix it through gcloud SDK using the command below:

`gsutil web set -m index.html -e index.html gs://your.bucket.com`

I had the same problem here and this is how I fixed it.